# Proving a subspace for the set of $M_{n \times n}(K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given a matrix $Y\in M_{n\times n}(K)$, consider the subset
$U_{Y}=\{X \in M_{n \times n}(K) \mid YX = 0 \} \subset M_{n \times n}(K)$ where $0$ denotes the zero matrix of size $n\times n$.
Prove that $U_{Y}$ is a subspace of the K-vector space $M_{n \times n}(K)$.

I've said because $YX = 0$, the zero vector belongs to $U_{Y}$.

For proving closure under addition, I've considered $X$ and $X^{'}$ in $U_{Y}$. Then since $YX + YX^{'} = 0 + 0 = 0$, $U_{Y}$ is closed under addition.

For proving closure under multiplication, I've taken some $\alpha$ in $K$. Then since $\alpha YX = 0$, $U_{Y}$ is closed under multiplication.

Is this a sufficient proof?

Comment: I think it is correct except for a typo. $Y0=0\Longrightarrow 0\in U_Y$

Comment: Given the elementary nature of the proof, I think that you should be more explicit with some details. For example, to prove the closure of the sum you need to consider $Y(X+X')$ but you skipped to $YX + YX'$. Similarly for the closure under scalar multiplication. At the level of someone that is learning the subject, I would expect something like $Y(\alpha X) = \alpha (YX) = \alpha 0 = 0$.